# Formatting tags relating to version numbers?

Tags: discussion, tags

Maybe it is because gis.stackexchange.com is only a day old, but the software/database/system tags don't include version numbers.  Sometimes the version doesn't matter, but for some questions, it will and I think there have been a handful of questions that already could be re-tagged to a specific version.

On stack overflow, the .net versions are ".net-3.5",  ".net-4.0", etc. Visual studio is: vs2008.

For questions that pertain to specific version(s), is there a standard way to notate the version in a tag?

For example: should an ArcGIS 10 tag be ArcGIS-10.0, ArcGIS10? Or is it just what gets used first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a dash is good, but a generic one should be left out if everyone is going to use it.  If they need to talk about multiple versions, then they can tag both.

Comment: Might we then see tags like `arcgis-8.3`, `arcgis-9.0`, arcgis-9.1`, `arcgis-9.2`, `arcgis-9.3`, and `arcgis-10.0` on the one post?  In otherwords, I think we should allow generic ones.

Comment: @fmark No - in that case I would tag using [tag:arcgis-8.3] and [tag:arcgis-10.0] to indicate the range of versions that the Q&A appears to apply to.

Answer (score 0):

I think version numbers are only useful (if at all) in closed source releases and major releases. I still would rather prefer to have the tags more generic. Having fifteen tags for arcgis alone renders the interesting / ignored feature useless.

I think people are better helped by mentioning version numbers early in the text than in the tags.

A specific version number is very helpful if answering a question, but the question might be valid for several version numbers.

Comment: I disagree with mentioning version numbers in the early part of the text instead of tags.  A lot of users, myself included, use the tags to create RSS feeds (do a search by tag and then scroll down to see the RSS feed link).   There are definitely uses for a generic non-versioned tag--no argument there.

Comment: People should be encouraged to use version tags only if there really is something version specific about their question, and it's perfectly okay for someone other than the poster to change a tag if it really isn't version specific.

Comment: Agreed. And I think you'll get users that are new to certain software who 'think' it's  version specific, but it's really not...and the old-timers can/should re-tag accordingly.

Comment: I agree with you, Jay. Maybe it would be good practice to encourage people to always use the generic tag as well. I.e. tag your ArcGIS 9.0 question as `arcgis arcgis-9.0`