# When Question is tagged arcgis10 should we assume arcgis-10.0 or arcgis-10.1 or ...?

Tags: discussion, tags

I would like to revisit [Formatting tags relating to version numbers?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22) from the early days of the GIS Stack Exchange from a slightly different slant.

When ArcGIS 10.0 was released there was little need to be precise and tag using arcgis-10.0 because ArcGIS 10.x came in just one flavour and arcgis10 was self explanatory.  However, since ArcGIS 10.1 was released, lots of ArcPy questions can now be answered quite differently if the asker is using 10.1 rather than 10.0 or 9.3 or ...

I would like to propose that when arcgis10 is entered as a tag, that it be synonymised with arcgis-10.1 so that a solution is first approached using the current version.  If the asker is using 10.0 or 9.3 then that will put the onus on them to inform us that we need to think about only options which were available with an older version.

Note: I do not advocate the use of Service Pack tags such as arcgis-10.1-sp1 unless perhaps a problem is encountered where that becomes highly relevant and needs to be highlighted.

Comment: Users should specify in their question the version they are using, some products (FME even states the build number clearly in the about section) - Which can be enough information to clear up related bugs on that build etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned, I have suggested that [arcgis10](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis10) be made a [synonym](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/arcgis-10.0/synonyms) of [arcgis-10.0](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-10.0). There are 23 questions tagged [arcgis10](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis10) and of these, almost all of them seem to be referring to ArcGIS 10.0, not 10.1. Thus making it a synonym of [arcgis-10.1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-10.1) would be counter-productive.

Comment: You are probably right that of the 23 tagged arcgis10 more than half probably involve(d) 10.0 (at the time they were asked).  However, if they remain issues in what is now the time frame of 10.1 then I think looking for answers from that perspective first would be more productive than pulling out the previous version.  Either way I would like to see the arcgis10 tag go.

Comment: I honestly think the recently tagged arcgis10 questions are from people that just don't know any better. They don't look like they're using 10.1, so there is no point in making it a synonym of that tag, but by making it a synonym of arcgis-10.0 the issue of having this redundant tag around will go away.

Comment: I've made a new [**Meta posting**](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3131/is-this-a-reasonable-way-to-use-tags-on-arcgis-questions) related to this one that I would be keen to hear your thoughts on.