# Asking same question with different technologies and/or environments

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

Based on the same idea about time related questions as described in [Asking same question for newer version](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4436), I'm wondering if it is OK or not to ask the same question with, as a target, a different software and/or environment. I'm having in mind GUI based tools (e.g. QGIS) vs tools that have to be run in a headless environment (e.g. Python scripts)?

In fact, I've already seen questions that were closed because they weren't focused enough when they concerned several software programs or libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain about what you are asking here but I think it is whether the following are three non duplicate questions:

1. Doing X using QGIS
2. Doing X using ArcGIS Pro
3. Doing X using PyQGIS

I think the three are distinct questions and if more than one of the three is asked in the same question then that question lacks the necessary focus for our focused Q&A format.

The third would almost always require a code snippet to be presented whereas the first two would usually need a series of steps to be described.