# How to easy search (using tags) - using *?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, search

Is there a way how to search for ideally all questions concerning e.g. ArcGIS when they do not have a tag [arcgis-desktop] **easier then manually listing all tags** like tags with different versions of arcmap, [arcpy] tag and others that could reliably say "this one refers to ArcGIS", **joined by "or"**?
(possibly combining with searching for some key words in text)

This approach would:

1. make quite a long string (that may not be even possible to write in the search line) with the need of using a number of "or"s and lot of typing
2. generate a lot of work searching for all possibly connected tags to include them in that list

I did not succeeded using asterisks (*) with tags.
Also did not see anything like "like" or "in" from SQL in [help for searching](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/searching) to be possible to use - but the later one woud do only minor help.
I do not mean using any restrictions in user profile concerning using tags.

The perfect solution within the given example would cover also tags like [modelbuilder] that do not contain "arc" or "arcgis" in the name of the tag but are surely connected with ArcGIS. This is questioned in [How to search for ALL questions concerning ArcGIS, QGIS or others?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4769/how-to-search-for-all-questions-concerning-arcgis-qgis-or-others)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do wildcard searching just type

`[arcgis*]`

into the search bar and you will see it expand to

`[arcgis-desktop] or [arcgis-10.0] or [arcgis-10.1] or [arcgis-10.2] or [arcgis-server] or [arcgis-javascript-api] or [arcgis-10.3] or [arcgis-online] or [arcgis-9.3] or [arcgis-10.4] or [arcgis-engine] or [arcgis-pro] or [arcgis-rest-api] or [arcgis-10.5] or [arcgis-silverlight-api] or [arcgis-flex-api] or [arcgis-web-appbuilder] or [arcgis-flex-viewer] or [arcgis-online-basemaps] or [arcgis-android]`

Unfortunately, there is a bug that prevents it getting all tags starting with `arcgis*` that is mentioned in [@blah238's answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3613/115) to [Using version tags?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3609)

To get all questions containing ArcGIS that are not tagged [arcgis-desktop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop) you can use:

`arcgis -[arcgis-desktop] is:question`

Comment: [arcgis*] - ok, using * in [tag] did not work for me, maybe sth wrongly written or so now it looks ok;       _and so it looks_ like for cases where arcgis* would not be (as it might not be) mention in the text (cannot use arc* for this for obvious reason).. and it would not be containing [arc*] tag but concerning arcgis this would not be easy/quickly/ to find but there would probably not be many of those...

Comment: Searching in the body should just need `ArcGIS` or `arcpy` as your strings.  The only things that won't pick up are when users use names like Arc, ArcEngine, ArcServer which are slang.

Comment: ok, and than there is that bug... :-(

Comment: I'm assuming `arcgis -[arcgis-desktop]` in the search bar (which you can then bookmark in your browser ) is the key to what you are trying to do.

Comment: You can __vote up__ for the __question regarding the bug that PolyGeo mentioned__ in this answer on [main meta stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231364/wildcard-tag-search-oes-not-expand-to-full-list-of-matching-tags). It seems it is not a bug just for  `[arcgis*]` but for any wildcard tag search (using *)

Comment: using * is one thing and it helpes a lot but what about, say __[modelbuilder]__? This one is connected with arcgis for sure but you cannot get that using * as they do not have any part of the word same... so what was in mind when writing the question was not only using * but also __"is there also something else to use in examples like the one with argis" to make the list of tags complete?__ ....edited question with the link and made this into 2 questions